# how to connect base64 image and send it using multipart?

Tags: angularjs, image, file, upload, ng-img-crop

Hi I am using `NgimgCrop` and i successfully got the base64 image Now I want to send it using multipart form data in `http post` request.

My file upload code look something look like this

```
scope.myCroppedImage = '';
    $scope.uploadFile = function (file) {
        if (file) {
            // ng-img-crop
            var imageReader = new FileReader();
            imageReader.onload = function (image) {
                $scope.$apply(function ($scope) {
                    $scope.myImage = image.target.result;
                    $scope.profileData.data = $scope.myImage;
                    console.log($scope.profileData.data);
                });
            };
            imageReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    };
```

Is there any way it convert it multipart after base64 in angular ? I tried various links but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send it with FormData:

```
YourAppName.config(function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {

    var fd = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(data, function(key, value) {
        fd.append(key, value);
    });

    return fd;

    }

});
```

Comment: You can use `config()` function to modify the `$httpProvider`. I've updated the code. I am afraid, if you are a newbie you will have a hard time getting this right.